# I have a pretty aggressive Betta

Tags: fish

I have a pretty aggressive Betta, ever since I did a full water change because it was getting too dirty. He got more aggressive than before, he flares up whenever he sees me, I've been wanting to get maybe some bottom feeders, would that be alright? I'm not sure whether or not he would kill them.

Comment: Are you asking about why your fish is more aggressive after a water change or are you asking whether you can keep bottom feeders with a betta?

Comment: How big is the tank?

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything is at risk of being attacked by or attacking a betta. **The best tank-mates that I found for a betta are snails.** Ramshorn snails. Maybe Malaysian Trumpets would be ok too. Shrimps will be eaten by betta, colorful fishes with beautiful fins will be atacked by betta. Tough or agressive fishes, or animals with poor eyesight might attack bettas because bettas are slow moving and have long waving fins that look like food. African dwarf frogs will try to eat these fins when they are in front of their nose.

Snails will clean your glass and clean the floor, although they also poo. They will help to recycle and decompose the waste.

Snail population numbers is a consequence of food available to them. If you overfeed your fish you will have more snails. Feed the minimum for the fish and you will have only a few snails.

Changes in water quality can affect a betta's coloration, health and behavior. Keep your tank clean but never change 100% of the water. Do regular 10-25% changes and don't clean the filter media or the substrate.

Hope that helps and your betta can have a cool life !